# Install app and make it undeletable

Tags: android

Does anybody has the Idea of making an android app undeletable.I want to install selected apps on the system memory so that anyone having an access to my phone cannot delete those apps even after resetting the phone...

What I earlier saw was that the apps installed on the system memory cannot be changed or modified by ordinary users...I tried resetting my phone but saw some apps preinstalled from the company remained and all the apps that were downloaded from the play store were deleted..

The answer I got from searching the web was that I could make install an Android app to the system memory...does it make the app undeletable even after resetting or formatting the phone?

Comment: Why? Outside of malware, there's no reason you should be doing this.

Comment: Even if you have a very noble reason for wanting this, I don't think it is possible to do it..

Comment: as a user, if you installed an app you could not delete, how would you feel?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by making your application by Developing a Device Administration Application, follow this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html.

Comment: Even for device administration applications, you can still drag the app from the app panel to delete it.  That will take you straight in to the flow where you can choose to disable it as an administration application.

Answer (score 0):

you could only do this if you root your phone and place the apps inside system/apps.

However, if this is about your phone, why don't you use a password protector for apps, so nobody can access the app manager?

Answer (score 0):

Removing a users choice to uninstall your app, goes against everything *most* programmers strive for. It's probably against the Google T&Cs also. And as already said, other than Malware or some dodgy virus attempt, there would be no practical (ethical) use for such an app, IMO.